# C++/Win32 Best encryption to fit my needs?

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption

I'm looking to encrypt data in chunks of 1024 bytes (not many). I don't mean generating a hash or compressing - just encrypt.

Looking for open source implementation + good algorithm.

**Order of importance**: (1) Simplicity (2) Speed (3) Strength

**Strength**: Solvable in reasonable time with a high end supercomputer

Comment: Simple Xor "encryption" is two way and is a simple loop over the buffer. It's not particularly strong though.

Comment: Xor is trivially easy to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/). It has many algorithms and I believe you don't have to take the library as a whole.

Comment: Yes, but bare in mind that Crypto++ has a tricky license.

Comment: (1) **simplicity** I want it to be simple enough for me to implement if I dislike the open source version.

Comment: I frankly don't understand why you should reinvent the wheel. Did you consider all the testing, bugs and other problems that would arise if you "disliked" the ready implementation? Quicksort, for example, is good and "easy" sorting algorithm. However, when given to a group of *professional* programmers, *80%* of them had some errors in their implementations. (Ref. from *Beautiful Code*)

Comment: I am looking for an open source, not commercial, implementation. Open source is not written by the top pier of professional programmers, and is likely to be improvable, by my standards.

Comment: I don't know what you're standards are, but if you think you will be able to improve open-source implementation, why even bother and don't write one from scratch?

Comment: Because my goal is finding the optimal practical solution, not writing code that I can avoid.